# Is this linker error in 32 bit Windows gFortran a bug?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following code compiles to 64 bit but the use of Fortran Generic Interfaces seems to confuse the gcc attribute in 32 bit (required to call the 32 bit STDCALL API). The code is a stripped down version of the [f03gl](http://www-stone.ch.cam.ac.uk/pub/f03gl/index.xhtml) project which I am attempting to build for Windows (I couldn't create a smaller repro).

A rework of the code (shown at the bottom) without the generic interface and passing arguments direct does compile and work. I'm hoping I won't have to rewrite all of the calls to work around this issue.

The error is;

```
callglutbad.o:callglutbad.f90:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `glutInit'
```

**callglut.f90 (fails 32 bit compilation)**

```
MODULE GlutModule
  USE ISO_C_BINDING
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PUBLIC glutInit

  INTERFACE glutInit
    MODULE PROCEDURE glutInit_f03
  END INTERFACE glutInit

  INTERFACE

    SUBROUTINE glutInit_gl(pargc, argv) BIND(C,NAME="glutInit")
      IMPORT

#ifdef x86
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES stdcall :: glutInit
#endif
      INTEGER(C_INT) :: pargc
      TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN) :: argv
    END SUBROUTINE glutInit_gl

  END INTERFACE

  CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE glutInit_f03()
    INTEGER(C_INT) :: argcp=1
    TYPE(C_PTR), DIMENSION(1), TARGET :: argv=C_NULL_PTR
    CHARACTER(C_CHAR), DIMENSION(1), TARGET :: empty_string=C_NULL_CHAR

    argv(1)=C_LOC(empty_string)
    CALL glutInit_gl(argcp, C_LOC(argv))

  END SUBROUTINE

END MODULE GlutModule

program main
  USE GlutModule

  PRINT *,"Calling glutInit"
  call glutInit()
  PRINT *,"Called glutInit"

end program main
```

**build.bat**

```
REM 32 bit 
@setlocal
@SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\
gfortran -Dx86 -cpp -c callglut.f90 -o callglut.o
gcc callglut.o -o callglut32.exe ..\x86\lib\freeglut.lib -lgfortran
@endlocal

REM 64 bit 
@setlocal
@SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\
gfortran -cpp -c callglut.f90 -o callglut.o
gcc callglut.o -o callglut64.exe ..\x64\lib\freeglut.lib -lgfortran
@endlocal
```

The generic interface is used to call glutInit without parameters from Fortran (the parameters are filled in by the proxy subroutine).

**callglut.f90 (compiles and runs on both platforms)**

```
MODULE GlutModule
  USE ISO_C_BINDING
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PUBLIC glutInit

  INTERFACE

    SUBROUTINE glutInit(pargc, argv) BIND(C,NAME="glutInit")
      IMPORT

#ifdef x86
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES stdcall :: glutInit
#endif
      INTEGER(C_INT) :: pargc
      TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN) :: argv
    END SUBROUTINE glutInit
  END INTERFACE

END MODULE GlutModule

program main
  USE GlutModule

  PRINT *,"Calling glutInit"
  call glutInit(0,C_NULL_PTR)
  PRINT *,"Called glutInit"

end program main
```

**Am I seeing a compiler bug with the attribute statement not being applied to a generic interface or is it something that I am doing?** I suspect this and the 32 bit STDCALL name mangling from glutInit to _glutInit@8 is not being performed.

I am using gfortran under msys2 (GNU Fortran (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.1.0) on 64 bit Windows with both 32 and 64 bit compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to apply the STDCALL attribute to an identifier that is only a generic name.  From the compiler's perspective, a generic name is a common label for a number of procedures.  While the individual specific procedures may have different calling conventions, the label for them does not.

If you want to tell the compiler that a specific procedure has a certain calling convention, use the name that the compiler knows the specific procedure by, in the relevant declaration.

```
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES stdcall :: glutInit_gl
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been banging my head against a wall on this. I assumed the name after :: was for the library exported name, not the local one. Quite confusing. Do you have any good references on this as I still find it confusing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "library exported name".  gfortran's compiler directives are documented at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GNU-Fortran-Compiler-Directives.html